# Any tool to help reviewing a website (snapshots, annotations, feedback)?

Tags: website, review

I'm looking for a tool (free/paid) to help me in reviewing my website style and interface. Such as: explain the content of the home page (footer, header, ...), take snapshots, and write comments on them.

I know this can be done using print screen and MS Paint, but I need a more professional tool to use.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: [Firefox addon to write annotations/notes for a web page?](http://superuser.com/questions/111867/firefox-addon-to-write-annotations-notes-for-a-web-page)

Comment: [Q&A is hard, let's go shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your annotating live websites (such as www.google.com). I used a tool when teaching, called [Diigo](http://www.diigo.com). It allows you to stick annotations on to web pages, and if you have friends added to this service then they'll be able to view remarks you've made. There is also a cool toolbar for Firefox that expands on this services usability.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Safari, [Coda Notes](http://www.panic.com/blog/2010/07/coda-notes-for-safari-now-available/) is an extension that allows you to directly annotate and send screenshots as email from your browser.